# How to append new values to hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

I have a hash of hashes where, at the last level, I want each value to be appended - **not updated** - if that value already exists. What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking about making the values as lists, but this is probably not the most efficient way...

Here's where I got so far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dir='D:\';

open my $data,"<","$dir\\file.txt";

my (@selecteddata,@array,%hash);

while (<$data>) {
    chomp $_;
    my @line= split "\t";

    $hash{$line[1]}{$line[2]}=$line[0]; 
    warn Dumper \%hash;
}
close $data;
```

Note, this code updates the values at last level with value `$line[0]`, but if the key `$line[4]` already exists (meaning, it already has a previous value `$line[0]`) I want this value to be appended and not updated.

So, ideally, for the following (tab sepparated) list:

```
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
a3  b3  c3
a4  b4  c4
a5  b4  c4
```

The hash would look something like this - I don't know exactly how the grouping of `a4` and `a5` should look like, so as long as they are grouped it should be ok:

```
{
    'b1'    =>  {'c1'   =>  'a1'},
    'b2'    =>  {'c2'   =>  'a2'},
    'b3'    =>  {'c3'   =>  'a3'},
    'b4'    =>  {'c4'   =>  'a4, a5'}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append your string,

```
$_ = defined($_) ? "$_, $line[0]" : $line[0] 
  for $hash{$line[1]}{$line[2]};
```

or use array which is better suited for storing list of elements,

```
push @{ $hash{$line[1]}{$line[2]} }, $line[0];
```